# Push Image from Openshift Imagestream to AWS ECR

Tags: docker, openshift, gitlab-ci, amazon-ecr

We have corporate Openshift Cluster, on which was configured Gitlab Runner.
I have no possibility to run Pods with root privileges or anyuid. Without root any docker, kaniko, buildah commands are failed.
I was able to build docker images only with standart Openshift tools:

```
oc get bc $APPLICATION_NAME || oc new-build --strategy docker --binary --name=$APPLICATION_NAME --to=$APPLICATION_NAME
```

Now i need to push this image from Openshift ImageStream to Aws ECR Repository. The Openshift ImageStream is only internal accessible.
Any Ideas?  I spent days but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to configure your `BuildConfig` to push your image to the external registry. An example can be found in an older blog post here: https://www.openshift.com/blog/pushing-application-images-to-an-external-registry

So basically you'll want to do `oc edit bc <mybuildconfig>` and then change the `spec.output` to something like this:

```
[..]
spec:
  output:
    to:
      kind: DockerImage
      name: myregistry.example.com/mynamespace/myimagename:latest
    pushSecret:
      name: registrysecret
[..]
```

The `registrysecret` you can create with a command like the following:

```
oc create secret docker-registry registrysecret --docker-server=DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER --docker-username=DOCKER_USER --docker-password=DOCKER_PASSWORD --docker-email=DOCKER_EMAIL
```

You can find more information in the OpenShift documentation:

- https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.6/builds/managing-build-output.html

Comment: Hi Simon, aws ecr get-login-password provide only 12 Hours Token to login into ecr. It is possible dynamically update Secrets from Running Pod? Thanks!

Comment: Not sure about ECR, I guess you'll have to work around that with something like the following: https://github.com/trondhindenes/ecr-updater

Comment: Thank you Simon, i will try this one